# compiling c++11 using make command

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, opencl

I am trying to compile my code on CPU using MobaXterm terminal and I use `make` command to compile my code. But many errors appears starting with the ones bellow. I searched online and understand that this is an issue with the compiler. But I am using `make` not `g++`. Any suggestion to solve these compilation problems.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/array:35:0,
                     from host/src/host.cpp:16:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
     #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
      ^
```

Makefile:

```
    ifeq ($(VERBOSE),1)
ECHO :=
else
ECHO := @
endif

# Where is the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software?
ifeq ($(wildcard $(INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT)),)
$(error Set INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT to the root directory of the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software installation)
endif
ifeq ($(wildcard $(INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT)/host/include/CL/opencl.h),)
$(error Set INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT to the root directory of the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software installation.)
endif

# OpenCL compile and link flags.
AOCL_COMPILE_CONFIG := $(shell aocl compile-config )
AOCL_LINK_CONFIG := $(shell aocl link-config )

# Compilation flags
ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
CXXFLAGS += -g
else
CXXFLAGS += -O2
endif

# Compiler
CXX := g++

# Target
TARGET := host
TARGET_DIR := bin

# Directories
INC_DIRS := ../common/inc
LIB_DIRS :=

# Files
INCS := $(wildcard )
SRCS := $(wildcard host/src/*.cpp ../common/src/AOCLUtils/*.cpp)
LIBS := rt pthread

# Make it all!
all : $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

# Host executable target.
$(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET) : Makefile $(SRCS) $(INCS) $(TARGET_DIR)
        $(ECHO)$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC $(foreach D,$(INC_DIRS),-I$D) \
                        $(AOCL_COMPILE_CONFIG) $(SRCS) $(AOCL_LINK_CONFIG) \
                        $(foreach D,$(LIB_DIRS),-L$D) \
                        $(foreach L,$(LIBS),-l$L) \
                        -o $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(TARGET_DIR) :
        $(ECHO)mkdir $(TARGET_DIR)

# Standard make targets
clean :
        $(ECHO)rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

.PHONY : all clean
  

       
                                 ^
```

Comment: First of all please [edit] your question to show your `Makefile` file, so we can see what flags and options you set for the compiler.

Comment: Please show the contents of your Makefile so we can best advise you on how to add the necessary compiler flags. Also note that GCC 4.8.2 is *ancient*.

Comment: Secondly, you should really upgrade your compiler. GCC 4.8 is **old**, and doesn't even have complete C++11 support.

Comment: Why cant you add `-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` to your options?

Comment: And to nitpick a little: You **are** using `g++`, through your makefile.

Comment: I add the Makefile, please check

Comment: That makefile seems very advanced. Did you write it yourself, or did you copy it from somewhere? Just copying "code" without to use without attempting to read and learn it is called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and is bad. Now if we read the makefile, you will see that the "compiler" will use the variable `CXX`. So from that we could deduce that flags for the compiler will be set in the `CXXFLAGS` variable. Now, you have to figure out *what* flag to set to enable C++11 (previously called C++0x) for your compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thank you for your replies. So, what do you suggest to type in the terminal

Comment: Nothing, you need to edit the makefile to update the flags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is the edit that you suggest to include in the makefile ??

Answer (score 1):

After many tries and suggestions, I finally find out the solution:

Edit my `Makefile` as follow:

```
    # Compilation flags
ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
CXXFLAGS += -g -std=c++11
else
CXXFLAGS += -O2 -std=c++11
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

That's more of a compiler issue and not and issue with `make`.

1. Check that the compiler is properly set up for the system you are on.
2. Also,if the compiler is well set up, check if it is compatible to compile C++11 standard as an older compiler could be the issue.

I think it would also be useful if you:
-include What OS you are on
-what compiler your are using

Let me know if this is useful.